Normality of Z[x]/(x^2 - n)
I am currently reading Ravi Vakil's notes on algebraic geometry and trying to solve exercise 5.4.I (a).
It asked to prove $ B = \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 - n)$ is a normal ring give n is a square-free integer and $n = 3 (mod 4)$. May I have some hints for solve this problem?
My attempt is:

suppose $\alpha \in K(B)$ such that $\exists \quad F[T] \in B[T]$ and $F[\alpha] = 0$. Then I can multiply $\bar{F}[T]$ to $F[T]$ to have $F[T]\bar{F}[T] \in \mathbb{Z}[T]$. Therefore, w.l.o.g. just assume $F \in \mathbb{Z}[T]$
On the other hand, suppose $\alpha = \lambda + \mu \sqrt{n}$, where $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then let $Q[T] = T^2 - 2\lambda T + \lambda^2 - \mu^2n \in \mathbb{Q}[T]$ and $Q[T]$ divides $F[T]$ in $\mathbb{Q}[T]$. Then by Gauss lemma, we have $2\lambda, \lambda^2-\mu^2n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Then I don't know how to use the condition of $n = 3 (mod 4)$.
